# Job queue alternatives to workling for use with rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, workling

[Workling](https://github.com/purzelrakete/workling) appears to be [incompatible](http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins/359-workling) with rails 3.  What alternatives are there for dealing with work queues in a rails 3 application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [quite a few options](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs).  Some of the top choices:

- [sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) - requires redis
- [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) - requires redis
- [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)
- [navvy](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/navvy)

Answer (score 1):

We use [Queue Classic](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic), which is simple, easily hackable and very powerful.

Answer (score -3):

[SimpleWorker.com](http://www.simpleworker.com) is a new Ruby workers as a service solution that takes all the infrastructure requirements out.

It's Rails 3 compatible and just as easy to use as the open source solutions.

Comment: You appear to have an interest in SimpleWorker...this should be disclosed in your post.